# Python Hog descriptor returns 0 or 1 if it detects/not detects the object

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a simple questions to ask,I am doing a real time detection with HOG descriptor,I want to know if there is a native function in HOG that returns true or false value to me so hat I can put it in my if else condition.

Example:

```
if(HOG.detected()):  //just a function I made up with,how do I get the hog to 
                     //tell me if I really did detect something with it?
//run the things I want
else:
//other action
```

My question is that is there any function in HOG that can do the things I stated?

Comment: Which HOG implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using HOGDescriptor

Comment: From what package?

Comment: I am not sure what you reallly mean,but this is the line I use HOG,hope it answers your question.

hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

Comment: What third-party packages are you importing that you use to create your HOG objects? Just trying to see if there's another tag you could add to get your question seen by more people who use the same packages.

Comment: I think I get what you mean,I also use:


from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression

Comment: Looks like ultimately it's using OpenCV, so I've added that tag.